# BFS vs Heuristics

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, heuristics

What is an example of Breadth First Search which still continues in real life example?

For example- I know that BFS is used in GPS navigations and digital maps, but A* is now used more often for better time complexity.

I am confused because BFS being a blind search technique, I think there will always be a heuristics beating it.

Also what are the circumstances under which BFS is unsuitable and a heuristic method is used?

Comment: Basically, every time where you can't have a reasonable heuristic. Also, BFS is used for many more problems than shortest path finding (e.g. region growing in a graph, connected component analysis...) BFS has some strong theoretical guarantees and I don't see how it can fail where a heuristic does not.

Comment: @Nico Schertler I changed question from fail to unsuitable!! Please review now!

Comment: Didn't you answer this question yourself? If you have a reasonable heuristic, you usually use it to speed up the search.

Comment: @Nico Schertler Also can you give an example when heuristics can't be obtained

Comment: @Nico Schertler I have only this readon to believe I should abandon BFS, is there any other concrete reason?

Comment: An example where you don't usually have a heuristic is a graph where the nodes do not have coordinates or the coordinates do not provide any meaningful information w.r.t. the distance of nodes. E.g. a network graph of computers. Or a graph of abstract states of a system.

Comment: @Nico Schertler I can't completely understand what you mean by node not giving any significant information. I guess a computer's location in an office is as important as a city's position.

Comment: Not if the wiring does not follow the direct path, which it usually doesn't. Wires run together to a switch, maybe one for each floor, maybe there are several interconnected switch layers. In the end, two computers that are physically right next to each other can be pretty far away in the network.

Comment: What heuristic would you use for : https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0mFP.png